# User modernizr to force browser to use jQuery UI datepicker instead of browser datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, modernizr

Some browsers natively support `date` type and have their own built-in datepickers, but I want to force every browser to use the jQuery.UI datepicker instead (because I need to be able to disable specific dates)

I found this code that will show jQuery.UI datepicker if browser doesn't natively support `date` type, but how would I fix this code so that it forces browser to use jQuery.UI datepicker ALL of the time?

```
if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
    $('input[type=date]').datepicker();
}
```

Comment: don't use input type="date"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `date` type inputs, just use `text` inputs. Since you don't care about date input support, you no longer need the Modernizr test. You may need to give them all the same class so that you can select them to initialize the date picker widget:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="date"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input.date').datepicker();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4V96Y/)**